# Firebase Firestore security rules how to chain logical operator AND / OR?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

This is the chat part of my app.  Chat messages are in a collection, named from hashing the usersIDs with the friendsID.  Each message document is titled by its Timestamp.

This security rule is rejecting every attempt to access the collection:

```
    match /messages/{messageThreadId}/{messageCollectionId}/{timeStamp} {
      allow read, write, update, delete: if request.auth != null 
&& (resource.data.idFrom == request.auth.uid || resource.data.idTo == request.auth.uid);
      allow create: if request.auth != null;
    }
```

I've tried loads of things, removing the bracket around the OR operator, hardcoding an ID as a String in the rules, which was a tell.  I've tried dialling back the rules to permit anyone logged in, that did work, but doesn't secure a user's messages.  So there's something awry with what this rule is actually doing.

What is the rule doing, or what's wrong with it?  How do I use the message document's `ifFrom` and `IdTo` String fields to filter?  Is it permissible to use more than one logical operator in a rule?  Are the brackets around the logic operating as you'd expect?

Here's the Firestore query that fails:

```
StreamBuilder(
              stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                  .collection('messages')
                  .doc(groupChatId)
                  .collection(groupChatId)
                  .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)
                  .limit(20)
                  .snapshots(),
```

I need it so only those who sent or received the message can read it, I need security rules to prevent eavesdropping.

Here is a message document:
[image: Firestore document example]

Comment: Security Rules don't mean anything without the Query being used to request the documents.  Please show the *precise* query you're using, and how it fails.  The most important thing to remember: **SECURITY RULES ARE NOT FILTERS**.  Your *QUERY* is the filter; all documents requested in a query MUST pass the Security Rule, or the entire query is rejected.

Comment: Thanks for the attention, more information provided.  I need rules to block eavesdroppers, so only those 2 folk participant in a chat can access their messages.

Comment: Your *query* *must* include idfrom and idto - security Rules WILL NOT only pass through the doxuments that match - THAT IS NOT HOW SECURITY RULES WORK. Security Rules DO NOT check your actual records - they check  if your query COULD access records that do not match rules, and BLOCK those queries.

Comment: Also note there are no "OR" queries, so in your case you will need TWO queries, one for idfrom and one for idto.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @LeadDreamer I have a solution.

LeadDreamer says for a query to pass a Firestore rule, all results of the query must also pass the Firestore rule.  So if you have a collection of blue elephants and a rich man, and you secure it with the rule 'only queries for blue elephants accepted' and then query Firestore for 'Everything please', well tough!  It's easier for a blue Elephant to fit through the eye of a needle than for the rich man to get round Firestore's security rule.  Proverb.

So I needed to reconfigure the message document so the Ids could be checked against the User's `request.auth.uid` I put them in an array firebaseIds, in the message document.  I From my flutter app I queried my message collection thus:

```
  : StreamBuilder(
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('messages')
          .doc(groupChatId)
          .collection(groupChatId)
          .where("firebaseIds", arrayContains: prefs.getString('firebaseId'))
          .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)
          .limit(20)
          .snapshots(),
```

The rules then query each message records array for the the users `auth.uid`:

```
   match /messages/{messageThreadId}/{messageCollectionId}/{timeStamp} {
      allow read, write, update, delete: if request.auth != null 
        && request.auth.uid in resource.data.firebaseIds;
      allow create: if request.auth != null;
   }
```

The flaw being a malicious user could hack the chat messages of those who communicate with them and delete or update their messages or write messages to them.  They could only do this in their message thread with them so I don't see this as a threat.

Firebase needed to create a composite index for me, automagically, to make this all work.